# How can this bit of Rails code be refactored?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Just out of curiosity:

How could this (rather ugly) Rails code be prettified / refactored:

```
def section_link(name, path)    
  link = link_to(name, path) 
  if name != controller.controller_name.titlecase
    link
  else
    link_to(name, path, :class => 'current')
  end
end
```

Comment: We have a sister site that answers code review questions: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - if you want I can migrate your question over there and you might get some more answers, one of which could be even better than the accepted one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def section_link(name, path)
  options = {}
  options[:class] = 'current' if name == controller_name.titlecase
  link_to name, path, options
end
```

Comment: Excellent, this one got the most votes, so I decided to go for it. Thanks!

Comment: not bad... but some programmers will chinge at this `options` being first `{}` and modified afterwards. Note that you can write the completely equivalent one-liner expression `options = name == controller_name.titlecase ? {:class => 'current'} : {}`

Comment: @tokland I'm not sure. If it were changing `options` to something else altogether, then I'd agree with you that initializing it to one value then changing it to another would be pretty yuk! (say it could either be `42` or `"the answer"`)

Comment: @Andy. At least it does not change its type, granted. But a question: when doing maths, if you write `x = 1`, do you change `x`, to let's say 2, afterwards in the same scope? No, that wouldn't make any sense. Why does it make sense when programming (which is just math in action)? (my point: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming).

Answer (score 5):

I'd write:

```
def section_link(name, path)
  is_current = (name == controller.controller_name.titlecase)
  link_to(name, path, :class => ('current' if is_current))
end
```

Justification: 1) The variable `is_current` makes the code somewhat more declarative. 2) `link_to` assumes that `nil`  means empty class (what we want here).

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
def section_link(name, path)
  link_to(name, path, class: name == controller.controller_name.titlecase ? "current" : nil)
end
```

But that's getting a bit hard to read. I would split the class determination into another method:

```
def section_link(name, path)
  link_to(name, path, class: class_for(name) )
end

def class_for(name)
  name == controller.controller_name.titlecase ? "current" : nil
end
```

Comment: well, you can also use variables. If `class_for` is used a number of time that's ok, if it's used just once, it's overkill.

Answer (score 0):

```
def section_link(name, path)     
  if name != controller_name.titlecase
    link_to(name, path)
  else
    link_to(name, path, :class => 'current')
  end
end
```

Or something like this

```
def section_link(name, path)
  link_to(name, path, :class => "#{"current" if name == controller_name.titlecase }")
end
```

Dont think it really needs refactoring tho, if it works...

Comment: I don't also get the -1. I strongly prefer the first snippet to the second though (this is too long and with a somewhat unclear string interpolation).

Answer (score 0):

```
def section_link(name, path)    
  link_to(name, path,
  *({class: "current"} if name == controller.controller_name.titlecase))
end
```

Comment: @tokland `nil` with the splat expands to absence in Ruby 1.9. And anything else other than an array expands to itself.

Comment: and what happens when it's not nil? > helper.link_to("a", "b", *({:class => "myclass"}))
NoMethodError: undefined method `stringify_keys' for [:class, "myclass"]:Array